# Solution for coupled equations with trigonometric functions

Tags: equation-solving, matrix

Suppose we have set of matrix equations, for this case lets consider a 2x2 set.
The equations are:

```
α*x*840.92 == 470.44*(Coth[α] - 1/α)+1329.74(Coth[β] - 1/β)

β*x*840.92 == 664.87*(Coth[α] - 1/α)+143.61(Coth[β] - 1/β)
```

I have tried using `NSolve` to no avail as it keeps the `Coth` unevaluated.

```
x=0.1
NSolve[{α*x*840.92 == 470.44*(Coth[α] - 1/α) + 1329.74*(Coth[β] - 1/β),β*x *840.92 == 664.87*(Coth[α] - 1/α) + 143.61*(Coth[β] - 1/β) && α > 0 && β > 
0}, {α, β}, Reals]
```

This just returns the same message.

The main idea is that for a given `x`, `α` and `β` can be calculated. 
I was trying to use a series expansion but the results are very unreliable I think. 
This should be able to work for any size matrix.

Comment: For those contemplating (0,0) as a solution, note the system is undefined at (0,0).  You'd have to clear denominators (including `Coth`) first, and then you can just plug in (0,0) to  set it's a solution of the resulting system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Updated for clarity**

It turns out there's a branch of solutions for `0 < x <= 0.500003` that you can get at with `FindRoot`. First, define

```
eq1 = α*x*840.92 == 470.44*(Coth[α] - 1/α) + 1329.74 (Coth[β] - 1/β);
eq2 = β*x*840.92 == 664.87*(Coth[α] - 1/α) + 143.61 (Coth[β] - 1/β);
```

and then rearrange these equations to get two definitions for `x` as a function of `α` and `β`:

```
x1[α_, β_] := (470.44*(Coth[α] - 1/α) + 1329.74 (Coth[β] - 1/β)) / (α*840.92)
x2[α_, β_] := (664.87*(Coth[α] - 1/α) + 143.61 (Coth[β] - 1/β)) / (β*840.92)
```

Then for any given `x`, the triplet `{α, β, x}` solves `eq1 && eq2` if and only if `x1[α, β] == x2[α, β] == x`.

### Finding the solutions

To get a sense of what's going on, we can plot `x1` and `x2` over the `{α, β}`-plane:

```
Plot3D[{x1[α, β], x2[α, β]}, {α, 0, 2}, {β, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"α", "β", "x"}, 
 PlotRange -> {All, All, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]

So we're looking for the intersection between those two surfaces. It's hard to see in the figure without rotating it, but there's something weird going on around `x == 0.5`. I'll go into a little more detail on this below, but basically, if you look at it as a bifurcation problem with `x` as the bifurcation parameter, then it turns out there's a nontrivial branch of solutions for `x <= 0.500003`.

Getting back to a numerical search for the solutions, you can use

```
x0 = 0.500003;
αβsol[x_ /; 0 < x <= x0] := FindRoot[
  {x1[α, β] == x, x2[α, β] == x}, {{α, 2., 10^-10, ∞}, {β, 1., 10^-10, ∞}}
]
```

or, if you just want the values and not replacement rules

```
αβsolvalue[x_ /; 0 < x <= x0] := {α, β} /. FindRoot[
  {x1[α, β] == x, x2[α, β] == x}, {{α, 2., 10^-10, ∞}, {β, 1., 10^-10, ∞}}
]
```

(where I've restriced `α` and `β` to be `>= 10^-10`, and started every search at `{α, β} == {2, 1}` simply because it works).

Plotting the solutions:

```
Plot[{αβsolvalue[x][[1]], αβsolvalue[x][[2]]}, {x, 0, x0}, 
  PlotLegends -> {α, β}, AxesLabel -> {x, None}]
```

[image]

Note that `{α, β} -> 0` as `x -> x0` and that the solution is undefined for `x = 0`.

Adding these solutions to the above plot of `x1[α, β]` and `x2[α, β]` shows that it's found the intersection of those two planes:

```
Show[
 Plot3D[
   {x1[α, β], x2[α, β]}, {α, 0, 2}, {β, 0, 1}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}],
 ParametricPlot3D[
   Flatten[{αβsolvalue[x], x}], {x, 0.4, x0}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}], 
 AxesLabel -> {"α", "β", "x"}
]
```

[image]

### Solution validity and error

To check that these solutions actually solve the equations I'll take some sample points

```
xvals = Range[0.001, 0.499, 0.001];
αβxvals = Flatten[{αβsol[#], {x -> #}}] & /@ xvals;

And @@ (eq1 /. αβxvals)
And @@ (eq2 /. αβxvals)

(* True
   True *)
```

Notice that I've left `x == 0.5` out of these solutions, even though it technically lies within the range of the nontrivial solution. This is because as `x -> x0` the solution branch converges to `{α, β} == {0, 0}`, which is undefined and causes the numerics to go a bit haywire (as shown in the next figure).

To get a better view of this, rearrange the equations once again to define:

```
f1[α_, β_, x_] := 470.44*(Coth[α] - 1/α) + 1329.74 (Coth[β] - 1/β) - α*x*840.92
f2[α_, β_, x_] := 664.87*(Coth[α] - 1/α) + 143.61 (Coth[β] - 1/β) - β*x*840.92
```

so that `{α, β, x}` solves the equations iff `f1[α, β, x] == f1[α, β, x] == 0`. Plotting these functions for `{α, β} == αβsolvalue[x]` shows that the error is indeed increasing as `x -> x0`:

```
GraphicsRow[{
  Plot[f1 @@ Flatten[{αβsolvalue[x], x}], {x, 0, x0}, 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "Error in equation 1"],
  Plot[f2 @@ Flatten[{αβsolvalue[x], x}], {x, 0, x0}, 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "Error in equation 2"]
  }, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

So as `x -> x0` the error in the solutions "explodes" to over `10^-11`, which is large enough for *Mathematica* to decide that the values do not solve the equations.

### The bifurcation at `x == x0`

Since we are looking for the zeros of `f = {f1, f2}` we can, with a bit of hand-waving, get some insight into the structure of the solution set by looking at the linearization of `f = {f1, f2}`.

```
f[α_, β_, x_] := {f1[α, β, x], f2[α, β, x]}
lin = D[f[α, β, x], {{α, β}}];
```

Evaluating in the limit as `{α, β} -> {0, 0}` and plotting the eigenvalues:

```
lin0 = Limit[lin, {α -> 0, β -> 0}]
Plot[Evaluate@Eigenvalues[lin0], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Clearly, one of the eigenvalues changes sign somewhere around `x = 0.5`, which indicates a change in the structure of the solutions (i.e.: a bifurcation). To pin down the bifurcation point, just solve for `x`:

```
x0 = x /. First@Solve[Eigenvalues[lin0][[2]] == 0, x]

(* 0.500003 *)
```

This is a long, *long* way from being a serious bifurcation analysis, so please don't quote me on it. Without more thought it grinds to a halt here because `f` is not actually defined at `{α, β} == {0, 0}`, so a whole bunch of tricks don't work and the analysis is on rather shaky theoretical grounds. However, something like this could work. And based on the numerics, it looks very much like there's a subcritical fold bifurcation at `x0`, and `x0` does appear to give a pretty accurate upper `x` limit for the existence of solutions:

```
Plot[αβsolvalue[x], {x, x0 - 10^-6, x0}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "α,β"}]
```

[image]

Comment: With x=.5, FindRoot for alpha and beta around 0.1 will yield Alpha = 0.0113836 and Beta = 0.00677112. For Alpha and Beta around 0.00001, Alpha= -3.97303*10^-6 and Beta=-2.36328*10^-6. The plot clearly shows the intersection at alpha=beta=0 and the fact that the FindRoot result changes when you change the value you want the root around it, tells me that it is just an approximation done by the software. mathematically, however, I believe the only real result is alpha=beta=0.

Comment: @NavidRajil I believe the first plot in my answer suggests otherwise -- those two surfaces intersect, whether we have access to a closed form solution or just a numerical one. At those intersection points `α` and `β` are such that `x1[α, β] == x2[α, β] == x`, and so `{x, α, β}` must solve the original equations.

Comment: The equations you construct with `x1[α, β]` and `x2[α, β]` are actually mathematically undetermined

Comment: Aardvark2012, The equations you construct with `x1[α, β]` and `x2[α, β]` are actually mathematically undetermined at alpha and beta equal to 0. The reason is that `(Coth[α]-1/α)/α` and `(Coth[β]-1/β)/α` are `0/0` when `α->0`, so as the counter parts with `α<->β`. So any result that the machine gives, is just an approximation. the real mathematical answer is zero for both alpha and beta. You can notice it if you increase your precision and make it go closer to zero.

Comment: @NavidRajil Leaving (0,0) aside, if you check aardvark2012's nonzero solutions, you'll see they satisfy the OP's form of the equations, which shows there are at least two solutions.  Given that (0,0) a removable discontinuity, hence special, my guess is that the nonzero solutions are more important.

Comment: Michael E2, of course the would solve the equations, specially if you plug them in through Mathematica, it will approximate an equality! and that is my point, approximate! '3.70437*10^-11' and '-9.14269*10^-13' are aardvark2012 solutions. one of them is negative which does not satisfy the original conditions of the question, being  `α, β>0`! As long as you can not prove the solutions are actual and not approximations, I will stand on my point that, as we increase the precision and the take the origin point for solutions closer to zero, answer of machine becomes smaller, so it's approximation.

Comment: @NavidRajil `3.70437*10^-11'` and '-9.14269*10^-13`` are not the solutions. They are the _errors_ in the solutions generated at `x == 0.5`, and they are substantially larger errors than for the other test points `0 <= x < 0.5`. The solutions are geneted by `αβvalues[x]`, and plotted in that last graph. I will try to clarify when I get a moment.

Comment: @NavidRajil For `x = 0.1`, I get `{\[Alpha] -> 19.3646, \[Beta] -> 9.01653}`, far from zero.  Since it's an odd equation, one also gets `{\[Alpha] -> -19.3646, \[Beta] -> -9.01653}`, but perhaps the OP is not interested is negative solutions.

Comment: Aardvark2012 and  Michael E2, I agree and I edited my solution. I just needed to plot it further up to alpha and beta around 21 and inspect it more. I got the same result you got aardvark2012, '{\[Alpha] -> 19.3646, \[Beta] -> 9.01653}'. Michael E2, these functions are symmetric with respect to origin so the negative solutions are also correct, but do not fit in the requested conditions. Again, around zero, machines' solution is an approximation. The real solution around origin is alpha=0 and beta=0.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yeah, I dithered over whether to include the negative solutions. They do give a nice symmetry to everything, but OP's `Solve` includes the conditions `α > 0 && β > 0`, so I left them off.

Answer (score 2):

You can use FindRoot if you where know the approximate result would be,

```
FindRoot[{α*x*840.92 == 470.44*(Coth[α] - 1/α) + 
1329.74*(Coth[β] - 1/β), β*x*840.92 == 664.87*(Coth[α] - 1/α) + 143.61*(Coth[β] - 1/β)}, {{α, 1}, {β, 1}}]
```

the plot will tell you:

```
Plot3D[{\[Alpha]*x*840.92, 470.44*(Coth[\[Alpha]] - 1/\[Alpha]) + 1329.74*(Coth[\[Beta]] - 1/\[Beta]), 664.87*(Coth[\[Alpha]] - 1/\[Alpha]) + 143.61*(Coth[\[Beta]] - 1/\[Beta]), \[Beta]*x*840.92}, {\[Alpha], 0, 21}, {\[Beta], 0, 11}, PlotLegends -> {"\[Alpha]*x*840.92", "470.44*(Coth[\[Alpha]]-1/\[Alpha])+1329.74*(Coth[\[Beta]]-1/\\[Beta])", "664.87*(Coth[\[Alpha]]-1/\[Alpha])+143.61*(Coth[\[Beta]]-1/\[Beta]\)", "\[Beta]*x*840.92"}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

My guess is both around zero or actually zero.

[image]

```
Manipulate[
Plot[{\[Alpha]*x*840.9, 
470.44*(Coth[\[Alpha]] - 1/\[Alpha]) + 
1329.74*(Coth[\[Beta]] - 1/\[Beta]), \[Beta]*x*840.92, 
664.87*(Coth[\[Alpha]] - 1/\[Alpha]) + 
143.61*(Coth[\[Beta]] - 1/\[Beta])}, {\[Alpha], -100, 
100}], {\[Beta], 0.0000001, 100}]
```

This Manipulate can let you change beta while you are plotting all RHS and LHS of your equations with respect to alpha. There is no place that they coincide except alpha=0 and beta=0. the other solution happens at `{\[Alpha] -> 19.3646, \[Beta] -> 9.01653}`. if you notice, orange and blue surfaces must intersect at those values and green and red also must intersect at those values. so, edited my answer and made it wider to have the other correct result mentioned.

Comment: Im assuming I dont know where the roots are.

Comment: I was adding the approximation part using Plot3D.

Comment: I double checked, the final answer is alpha=0 and beta=0.

Comment: For these equations, `alpha = 0` and `beta = 0` are true and the values are independent of the value of x.  This can be seen by `Limit[Coth[x] - 1/x, x -> 0] = 0` making the rhs and lhs of each equation 0 when `alpha,beta = 0`.  When using NSolve you generally do better with exact values in your equations, but in this case, `FindRoot` is the better choice.

Comment: The `Manipulate` has a list of four components, yet shows only two curves. It might be instructive to understand the implications of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
eqns = α*x*840.92 == 
      470.44*(Coth[α] - 1/α) + 
       1329.74*(Coth[β] - 1/β) && β*x*840.92 == 
      664.87*(Coth[α] - 1/α) + 
       143.61*(Coth[β] - 1/β) // Rationalize // Simplify;

x = 1/10;

{#, FindRoot[eqns, {{α, 10^-9, 10^-6}, {β, 10^-9, 10^-6}}, 
     WorkingPrecision -> #] // N} & /@ Range[25, 125, 50]

(* {{25, {α -> -9.34083*10^-23, β -> -7.50174*10^-23}}, 
    {75, {α -> 3.73705*10^-55, β -> 3.00204*10^-55}}, 
    {125, {α -> -1.24106*10^-79, β -> 1.45138*10^-80}}} *)
```

The higher the precision, the closer the values are to zero. This indicates that the roots are zero.